# UIBarButtonItem's don't appear after Fingerprint Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, touch-id

I am creating an app, and to access the `main screen` of the app the user has to input there `fingerprint`. I have it setup so that when the `fingerprint` is correct it programmatically performs a `segue` to a `navigation controller` which is connected to the `main view controller`. Here is my code:

```
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {

        let reason = "Authenticate with Touch ID"

        context.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply:
            {(succes: Bool, error: NSError!) in

                if succes {

                    self.showOrHide(true)
                    ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("passwordCorrectSegue", sender: nil)

                } else {

                }

        })

    } else {

        self.touchIDLabel.hidden = true
        self.touchIDImage.hidden = true

    }
```

The problem is when I `perform the segue` and it goes to the `navigation controller` which shows the `view controller`, the `UIBarButtonItem's` do not show on the top left and top right of the screen. You can still click on the top left and top right of the screen and the actions for those buttons would run. The problem is that the `UIBarButtonItem's` are just not showing. Another thing I have tried is that you also have the option to enter in a password, and when the password is correct it goes to the next `view controller`... and it works perfectly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The `UIBarButtonItems` just don't show when I use the method

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("passwordCorrectSegue", sender: nil)
```

when trying to perform that method using the fingerprint method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue: I have 2 VC, each being able to segue to a third one ; if I segue from the first, the right bar button item is not visible (but still works), but if I segue from the second one, the right bar button item is visible.

I guess it's a bug in iOS9.

The workaround I used was to force the initialization of the right bar button item in the destination view controller "viewDidLoad":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Force right bar button item when using performSeguewithIdentifier (bug in iOS9?)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(assetIdentifier: .Profile),
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
    target: self,
    action: Selector("displayUser"))
}
```

That fixed the issue for me (at least until Apple fixes this bug).